# Class inheritance across files

Tags: python, class

I'm struggling with some definition of inherited classes, accross multiple files.

I've searched for a long time, and found some examples, but none that solved my issue.

Let's dive into an example:

file1.py:

```
from file2 import SubClass

class MainClass:
  def __init__(self):
    print("This is MainClass")

mc = MainClass()
mc.SaySomething()
```

file2.py:

```
from file1 import MainClass

class SubClass(MainClass):
  def SaySomething(self):
    print("This is the subclass")
```

My goal is to split up a huge class into multiple files, each containing some related functions.

I've tried a lot of different combinations, but always get an error - it's different when I change something of course, but the result is the same; it doesn't work.

I guess it's related to the way I try to import each file into each other, but I haven't figured out how to do it, so I hope someone can solve it, and explain it to me.

Actually a third file is will import the main class and execute it. I guess that file only need to import file1.py, as it will import file2 - otherwise correct me, please.

Okay, so that's part one. However, I'm also curious if theres a way of which I can make some multiple nested modules/functions in the object - for the structures sake.

I'm quite sure an example will explain it better. Can I make something like:

```
mc = MainClass()
mc.SubClass.SaySomething()
```

...instead of just `mc.SaySomething()`? This way I can keep a way better structure of the code, I think.

Comment: This is called a circular import. In file1, you import smth. from file2 and vice versa. This is almost always an indication that you should change your design.

Comment: `from file2 import SubClass` is not needed, you're not using `SubClass`

Comment: I'm not sure how file1.py then should know that there's defined a subclass?

Comment: @KasperLeth A base class rarely has to know about its subclasses. I think before you start splitting up source code into separate files/modules first you should have solid understanding of software design (especially OOP design in case of python). Focus on that part first because this file-splitting cosmetics thingy is really unimportant compared to good design even in case of software with millions of lines of code with several thousand lines long source files.

Comment: I don't think I'm clear on what you're really trying to accomplish here. Saying something like `mc.SubClass.SaySomething()` seems like it defeats the point of inheritance. You don't *want* to specify a specific subclass when invoking an inherited method...

Answer (score 1):

You could refactor your code to make multiple classes minimizing dependencies (as self-contained as they can get). Then instead of inheritance try *composition*. Which means employ duck typing instead of parent-child relations. The inheritance route won't work because that would mean weird circular imports. So,

```
# a.py
class A:
    # some code
# b.py
import a
class B:
    aobj = a.A()
    # go on using aobj
```

*But, instead of all this you should always prefer revisiting your design, cleaning it up, so that it becomes more readable. Moreover it might also happen that the seemingly large class might be cleanly split in to multiple chunks, if parts of the code are found to be unrelated after some inspection.*

Answer (score -1):

What I understand you want to do, you shouldn't do.

Maybe you want to do multiple inheritance, I hope you understand it with the following example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def increase(self):
        self.number += 1

class B:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def decrease(self):
        self.number -= 1

class AB(A, B):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

ab = AB(10)
ab.increase()
print ab.number
```

By this way you can split your classes in diferent files and then make a MainClass, but I don't think it will be the best way.

Comment: Note that circular imports are possible in Python.